Удаление программы через командную строку (cmd) с названием в кириллице
При удалении программы из "Программы и компоненты" через командную строку
данная команда выдает ошибку Отсутствуют экземпляры. по причине того что не распознает кириллицу.
wmic product where name="Программа_0.1.23" call uninstall /nointeractive

Очевидно что проблема с кодировкой.
Подскажите как обойти данную проблему.

"по причине того что не распознает кириллицу", "Очевидно что проблема с кодировкой" - это не очевидно и в вопросе не приводится никаких пояснений, относительно того, как вы пришли к такому выводу.

Потому-что программы с названием в английском алфавите успешно удаляются, а на кириллице нет

А вот этот тред читали, может что полезное для себя почерпнёте: https://forum.ixbt.com/topic.cgi?id=22:90490

Да я недавно нашел его, но еще не успел проверить на практике то что там советуют.

Самый лучший совет -- никогда не используйте символы отличные от ascii в именах объектов файловой системы (его можно  еще усилить -- пробелы, табуляции, знаки пунктуации  и т.п. также не используйте)

Совет отличный полностью согласен, но не я же эту прогу так называл.

никогда не используйте символы отличные от ascii в именах объектов файловой системы - а как же тогда сделать невидимый ярлык в винде, если не использовать nbsp в имени? )))

Подскажите как обойти данную проблему - подсказываю: chcp 1251, и уже потом wmic product ...

если не поможет - то 866
